# Maple package for Latex

Tags: math-mode, listings, verbatim

I'm translating the book PHYSICS WITH MAPLE by Wang. It contains some codes and outputs from Maple of course.

I was wondering do we have a package such as mcode or matlab-to-tikz ( MATLAB) for Maple too?

The actual problem raises when I have formulas + codes in a box and I have to change the environments  from verbatim or listing to math ones  or using some specific commands over and over, it sometimes gets really exhausting. 
 Besides I like to have high quality graphs which changes when I alter the code and run the program ,as it does in matlab-to-tikz.

Here is a very basic sample of one of the boxes.
[image]

Comment: What about export option of maple. It has some built in latex styles in the ETC folder.

Comment: I am not sure to understand: you sometimes want to plot mathematical functions calculated with Maple with TikZ?

Comment: That looks very much like `maple2e` package which is `% Copyright (c) 1994--1998 by Waterloo Maple Inc., all rights reserved.` Imho this package is not on CTAN but you might find it with your favourite search engine.

Comment: @ Harish the export only covers the formulas not the codes

Comment: @ Pluton Yes, I want to do exactly what I do with matlab to tikz which makes me able alternate the plots simultaneously when I make any changes in the source code, but I don't care if it's available with Tikz , Pstricks or any other package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `maple2e` package to include maple plots.

Here is an example of what that would look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{maple2e}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}%
{plot3d(sin(x)*cos(y),x=-3..3,y=-3..3,axes=`normal`);}{}
\end{mapleinput}

\mapleresult
\begin{center}
\mapleplot{test101.eps}
\end{center}

\end{maplegroup}
\end{document}
```

source: http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/maple-images.html