# LaTeX: Syntax highlighting for Maple, Mathematica, Sage

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, highlighting

I'm typing up a short comparison of Maple, Mathematica, and Sage in LaTeX.  My problem is this: I'd like to include highlighted source code in one column (left) and output in another (right).

I know how to split the view with `minipage`, and about the `listings` and `minted` packages.  I've got nice highlighting for Sage by using the `python` language setting for `minted` and would like to stick with that package.  However, I have not been able to get `minted`  to properly highlight Maple or Mathematica code.  Since these two programs are well-known among TeX users, I was thinking that someone might have a solution.  It would be nice if I could download the Maple and Mathematica styles.

Otherwise, is there some "best fit" style that I could use for acceptable highlighting?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.  Also, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. This makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:  I'm not aware of a single solution that will do all three languages, at least not without some work on your part.  `listings` will likely be easiest.

`minted` uses the [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) syntax highlighter.  Pygments currently doesn't support Maple or Mathematica (at least, not unless you can track down someone's custom lexer).  So the only way to proceed with `minted` is probably to write your own lexer (might not be that difficult, but I've never tried).

`listings` supports Mathematica and Python, but not Maple (but you might look at [this](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/support/?153)).  So if you go that route, you will need to define a language (this shouldn't be too difficult; you could start with the link above, and customize to your needs).

Regarding other options:  The program [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/) can highlight Maple and export a LaTeX version.  It also does Python, but not Sage or Mathematica.  [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) doesn't have Mathematica or Maple.  I've never used either of these.  I think that covers all the standard and fallback syntax highlighters (there's also [t-vim](http://modules.contextgarden.net/vim), but that's for ConTeXt).  There are also some language specific options, for example, evidently there's a `maple2e` package (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66143/maple-package-for-latex)).

You should keep in mind that Sage and Python aren't completely identical (for example, `^` vs. `**` for exponents).  If you want a more Sage-specific solution, you might see the `sagetex` package's approach to using Sage with `listings`. Basically, it defines a new Sage language based on Python, for the Sage console (just search the `sagetex` documentation for `\lstdefinelanguage{Sage}`, and take a look at what follows).

Comment: I found a similar answered question on [mathematica.stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42793/highlighting-mathematica-code-in-latex-document), of course only for the mathematica part…