# Export datas which we derived in Maple to Latex

Tags: packages, external-files, maple2e

I have a numerical solution for an ODE. (You can find the attached Maple code: [numerical_solution.mw](https://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=224414_question/numerical_solution.mw))

What are the simple methods in order to create a table in Latex as follows by using these datas which we derived in Maple?

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a package, [`maplestd2e.sty`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=latex/viewing), that integrates with [Maple's LaTeX export capability](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet%2Fmanaging%2Fexporttolatex) to accomplish this.

So you should be able to just export it and include it as described in the [documentation](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet%2Fmanaging%2Fexporttolatex).

This has also been [discussed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68864) [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109269) on this site (there are notable limitations to this approach).

---

Alternatively, you could save the table as a CSV (e.g. via [`ExportMatrix`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=ImportMatrix)) and use the [`csvsimple`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) package to include it within your LaTeX document.

Comment: @1_student If this answer was useful to you, please consider accepting it.